# AutoMapper global pre/postfixes

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

According to [these lines](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/6551613bcae9f391c50d392d94b5e5aad800a27f/src/AutoMapper/ProfileMap.cs#L54), `GlobalIgnores`, `SourceExtensionMethods`, `AllPropertyMapActions` and
`AllTypeMapActions` of a profile are all concatenated with the global configuration.

`Prefixes` and `Postfixes` are not however, preventing the use of a global pre/postfixes definition.

```cs
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(config => {
    // Only effective for map created from config
    config.RecognizePostfixes("Id");
    config.AddProfile<SomeProfile>();
});

class SomeProfile : Profile
{
    public SomeProfile ()
    {
        // One would have to uncomment this line for "Id" postfixes
        // to be recognized while mapping from SomeDto to SomeObject
        //config.RecognizePostfixes("Id");
        CreateMap<SomeDto, SomeObject>();
    }

}
```

Is there a way to apply pre/postfixes globally without relying on profile inheritance ?

Comment: Make the change, if all the tests still pass, you can open a PR.

Comment: Just did : https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/3518